# Apache OFBiz Xml Data export issues

Tags: xml, ofbiz

I am using Apache OFBiz for my organization. Recently I migrated ofbiz from derby to mysql database, the problem is while I am exporting all entities using \Webtool\XML Data Export some entities such as **PartyAndUserLogin** are not exported and output message for them are **[1] [vvv] PartyAndUserLogin skipping view entity.** 
Can any one help me that how to export all Entity from Ofbiz\Webtools without facing such a message and problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PartyAndUserLogin is a view entity, it is a combination of the Party and the UserLogin entities, if you already exported those entities, the PartyAndUserLogin entity will work, no need to export it.